# PHP how to store GET variables to use it later

Tags: php

I wrote a simple php(html) script to show me a status. Via JQUERY the status update happen automatically. A few parameters are provided from another script and sent via `GET` to the status script.
So the idea was to use `S_SESSION`

```
    if( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE ) // if session status is none then start the session
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['dur'] = 10;
    $_SESSION['gDur'] =  0;
}else{
    error_log("ShowListeners Session: " . var_export($_SESSION, true),0);
}
if(isset($_GET['dur'])){
    error_log("ShowListeners GET: " . var_export($_GET, true) , 0);
    $_SESSION['dur'] = $_GET['dur'];
    $_SESSION['gDur'] =  $_GET['gDur'];
}
```

In the part where I try to read the session data

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['dur']))
        $ret .= getTimeString($_SESSION['dur']);
```

`$_SESSION['dur']` is always not existing. I also can see, that every time the script is called, `session_start()` is called because I can not see any error_log!

Do I something wrong or is it not possible to store the data in a session variable?

**Edit(2021-08-08)**

In the meantime I have read a lot about `SESSION`. I understand, that `SESSION` are related to users or cookies. But what is not clear to me, is there any possibility to make sure, that several instances can access the same `SESSION` data? For example, there is a instance running and another instance get over `GET` an data update. Can this instance access and modify the `SESSION` date used by the first instance?

Comment: Please start `session_start()` above if condition

Comment: Rinshan, do I understand it right? I should use `Session_start` before checking the status? But is than the `session`  not started anyway and `session_status()` check makes no sense anymore?

Comment: `if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)` always gives 1 means true as output with your code

Comment: Sorry, I am also bit confused by running multiple php versions for deleting and adding comments

Answer (score 1):

I think that your first condition scope can be the cause of your problem..., why don't you call "session_start()" everytime ?

Here's my proposition that you can try :

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['dur'])) {

    $_SESSION['dur'] = 10;
    $_SESSION['gDur'] =  0;
}
if(isset($_GET['dur'])) {

    $_SESSION['dur'] = (int) $_GET['dur'];
    $_SESSION['gDur'] = (int)  $_GET['gDur'];
}
```

Comment: OK it is working for the new instance. But I want to send these data to all instances, which are already running. Is this possible?

Comment: every client has a different session; if you want to share across all, you might have to look into using redis and on all request you read the same key from redis